What exactly is a scratch file (starting with #)? Does it still work today?
I've been reading up on some Unix history and got interested into the csh because it's installed by default on OpenBSD.
In the csh manpage it had a reference to "W Joy - An Introduction to the C shell", which I could get a hold of. Therein, in Chapter 1.3 it explains simple file redirection and makes an example, quite perplexing to me:

The system normally keeps files which you create with ‘>’ and all other files. Thus the default is for
files to be permanent. If you wish to create a file which will be removed automatically, you can begin its
name with a ‘#’ character, this ‘scratch’ character denotes the fact that the file will be a scratch file.* The
system will remove such files after a couple of days, or sooner if file space becomes very tight. Thus, in
running the date command above, we don’t really want to save the output forever, so we would more likely
do
date > #now


Now I never heard of a scratch file. Is this a long forgotten thing? Does it still work today? Is it just disabled? When will it get deleted (couple days?)? by what (cron?)?
I've run the command on an OpenBSD and on a Linux System (date > '#now' because its a comment in /bin/sh), but I can't wait (or might just answer myself in a "couple days").
Does anybody know more about this, preferably some more history. I couldn't find anything from few a quick searches.
Thanks in advance!

Perhaps another reason why (csh is evil)[http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/]. Otherwise, I've never run across this statement and any file deletions would need to occur at the OS level, not from the shell.


Was there a date on the Joy document? 2) my version of csh doesn't mention scratch files 3) Anderson & Anderson's The Unix C Shell Field Guide (1986) has no scratch files listed in  it's very well drawn index at the back. It refers to  # as the hash mark, and the index entry for hash mark lists a) comment char b) num of words in a variable, i.e. echo ${#var} 4). I recall hearing main frame programmers referring to scratch files, so it could have been provided becuase some ancient alpha csh tester had worked with mainframes (just a wild guess).



if for some reason you need to use csh, that A&A Csh Field Guide is a really excellent tech writing and will give you a big leg up. It's explanation of cmd-history editing using !! and related syntax is eye-opening. Table 6-2 'Cmd History Summary' has 30+ syntax examples how you access any line or word previously typed, and make substitutions atomically to indvidual words. BUT csh does have serious limitations as a scripting langage, don't waste your time, unless you're getting the big consulting bucks (-;


What version of BSD UNIX was being described in Chapter 1.3?  The "scratch file" functionality has likely not survived into the modern day.  I knew nothing of it in the SunOS 4.1.{2,3,4} versions I worked with in 1994-1997 (which, IIRC, was based on 4.3BSD).

The syntax with the hash file name has not survived in modern linuxes. Cleanup of scratch directories is still in use (and actually a default under the current Fedora), see https://serverfault.com/questions/377348/when-does-tmp-get-cleared

Always mount a scratch monkey.


Now I never heard of a scratch file. Is this a long forgotten thing? Does it still work today? Is it just disabled? When will it get deleted (couple days?)? by what (cron?)?

Automatic deletion of junk files via cronjobs used to be common on multi-user Unix systems, from what I have read. (At least automatic deletion of core dumps – plenty of stories about people naming their most important project ~/core and losing it the next week.)
By default, Emacs creates temporary files named #foobar.txt# wherever the original is edited. It is very conceivable that a multi-user Unix that the FAQ's author had an account on, especially if it was often short on disk space, would have had a custom cron job to automatically delete these files if they were older than X amount of days.
Indeed as discovered by Stéphane Chazelas this used to be default in 3BSD once upon a time (copied here in case mods decide to purge comments again):

See this crontab in 3BSD from the late 70s (where the csh man page already had that verbiage) that deletes such files in /usr. – Stéphane Chazelas

Today any such automatic cleanup is usually confined to /tmp and sometimes /var/tmp.

1 See for example the multiple find mentions in this collection. See also 2, 3, 4 for more (Unix and other) computing history from that era.

See this crontab in 3BSD from the late 70s (where the csh man page already had that verbiage) that deletes such files in /usr

IIRC the find /usr is because in that era user accounts lived under /usr, and /home didn't exist

I like how that crontab also deletes files under /usr/preserve

Scratch files were introduced for passes on a PDP 11 and later on large UCB systems which had a /tmp like disk which was being cleared on reboot and later for prod uses every day with a cron like script. Those files had nothing to do with csh or any other shell. It was an old Unix feature. Nowadays you can make your own temp files with what ever prefix you like and create a cron that will delete them every now and then
PS. I did read a more detail desription somewhere, but I cannot remember where.
